# R dplyr subset with missing columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset

I have the following code and would like to select columns into a new `data.frame`.

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(
    Manhattan=c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), 
    Brooklyn=c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
    The_Bronx=c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), 
    Staten_Island=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), 
    "2012"=c("P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q"), 
    "2013"=c("P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "Q", "Q", "P", "P", "P", "P", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q"), 
    "2014"=c("P", "P", "P", "Q", "Q", "P", "P", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "P", "Q", "P", "P", "P", "Q", "Q"), 
    "2015"=c("P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "Q", "Q", "Q", "P", "Q", "P", "P", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q"), check.names=FALSE)
df2 <- subset(df, select = c("Manhattan", "Queens", "The_Bronx"))
```

This throws the error:

```
Error in [.data.frame`(x, r, vars, drop = drop) : 
   undefined columns selected
```

Because the column "Queens" is missing from `df`. How can I can override the error, so that R proceeds to create df2 with columns "Manhattan" and "The_Bronx" only?

Very important: My real data have hundreds of columns, so it is not doable to manually remove columns like "Queens" from the command `df2 <- subset(df, select = c("Manhattan", "Queens", "The_Bronx"))` (unless there is a trick for that?). Is there a way to solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In base R, you can use `intersect` to select only the names which are present.

```
cols <- c("Manhattan", "Queens", "The_Bronx")
subset(df, select = intersect(names(df), cols))

#   Manhattan The_Bronx
#1          1         1
#2          1         1
#3          0         0
#4          1         0
#5          1         0
#6          1         0
#7          1         0
#8          0         0
#...
#....
```

Or use `any_of` in `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% select(tidyselect::any_of(cols))
```

Comment: Whoah! Terrific! Thank you so much your quick solution! :)

Comment: Hi, why my R returns "Error: 'any_of' is not an exported object from 'namespace:tidyselect'"?

Comment: @Negrito Probably you need to upgrade to latest version of `tidyselect`. What is your `packageVersion('tidyselect')` ? Mine is 1.0.0 .

Answer (score 1):

We could also do

```
cols <- c("Manhattan", "Queens", "The_Bronx")
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   select(matches(str_c(cols, collapse="|")))
```

Answer (score -1):

The current version of dplyr supports passing a character vector of variable names into the second argument to `dplyr::select()`, but recommends wrapping that vector in `all_of()` to reduce ambiguity.

```
varnames <- c("mpg", "cyl", "carb")
```

the following two lines both produce the the same output:

```
dplyr::select(mtcars, varnames)
dplyr::select(mtcars, all_of(varnames))
```

output:

```
                     mpg cyl carb
 Mazda RX4            21   6    4
 Mazda RX4 Wag        21   6    4
 Datsun 710           23   4    1
 Hornet 4 Drive       21   6    1
```