# How make R ignore undefined columns selected error message in cbind()?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe A, and want to merge a column that exists in A with ones that do not exist in A. I want to make cbind ignore those columns that does not exist and cbind() only existing ones. Something similar to `cbind(A$Key.Name,A$Dummy1,A$Dummy2)`, however preserving dataframe class of the data with the column names.

```
A<-fromJSON('[{"Key":{"Name":"Victor","ID":61426},"Type":"Unknown","Domain":"Cooking"  }]',
            flatten = T)

names(A)
cbind(A["Key.Name"],A["Dummy1"],A["Dummy2"])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R dplyr subset with missing columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61152518/r-dplyr-subset-with-missing-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `intersect` to select only those columns that are present in the data.

```
cols_to_select <- c('Key.Name', 'Dummy1', 'Dummy2')
result <- A[intersect(names(A), cols_to_select)]
```

In `dplyr` you can use `any_of` :

```
library(dplyr)
A %>% select(any_of(cols_to_select))
```